# Double Range Slider issue

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm having a problem with custom double range slider. The issue is when i slide the thumbs they are crossing each other and max thumb going towards min thumb and vice versa.

to be more clear i have created a sandbox.[slider](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-kapitsa-zy839d?file=/package.json)

I have tried to delay the request time using debounce to prevent continuously requesting to backend everytime when value changes. After that i had an issue with range background color cause i was delaying setting the input value. I have fixed that somehow but faced the problem above

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.